# usage of jxcore packaging?

Tags: node.js, packaging, jxcore

I am curious to know the usage of packaging the node application into **.jx** and **.jxp** format using JXcore.

As I gone through [this document](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/blob/master/doc/api/jxcore-feature-packaging-code-protection.markdown#jx-package), it is converting application into binary format for code protection.

Is there any other usage other than this?

Answer (score 1):

Main purpose of `JXcore` packaging is making the deployment easier. Originally developed for mobile applications, packaging backend powers `Android APK` virtualization for `node.js` mobile applications.

Comment: can i get any step by step tutorial to do this??

Comment: to this ? Android APK? See github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova